# Make OpenJ9 class sharing also share non-boot classes

Tags: java, docker, metabase, openj9

We run dozens of Docker containers (Metabase BI tool, a Java application) on a single server (with Docker Compose) and would like to optimise the memory footprint.

I have enabled class sharing by providing the following Java options:

```
-Xquickstart -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=/cache,verbose,checkURLTimestamps,persistent -Xscmx300M
```

But I am only able to have Java share its own libraries code:

```
root@f7dc95f540cf:/# java -Xshareclasses:cacheDir=/cache,printStats=classpath
1: 0x00007F5ACE807F1C CLASSPATH
    /opt/java/openjdk/lib/modules

Current statistics for cache "sharedcc_root": 

Cache created with:
    -Xnolinenumbers                      = false
    BCI Enabled                          = true
    Restrict Classpaths                  = false
    Feature                              = cr
```

Is there a way to have OpenJ9 also share all application classes?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your application class loader extends URLClassLoader, OpenJ9 should be able to cache the application classes loaded by that class loader. By default OpenJ9 only caches AOT code in the startup period that it detects, but if you dropped -Xquickstart and ran with -Xtune:virtualized instead, more caching of AOT code would also occur (throughout the run, i.e. post startup period as well). This may or may not help your scenario but I thought I would mention it. Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading from Java 11 to 13.